# Collection view dequeueing same cell for consecutive index paths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Has anyone run into the issue where a UICollectionView dequeues the same cell for consecutive indexpaths? This is happening when I call

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

The result is all cells are blank except for the cell with the address that was dequeued.

Comment: `The result is all cells are blank` that sounds like your delegate not handling that deletion correctly when re-constituting the cell. Of course depending on your layout size etc. when you delete things in the middle multiple cells can be dequeued and of course they will have the same indexpath (coz they will keep filling the same indexpath to make up for deleted items...)

Comment: When you say your delegate not handling that deletion correctly when re-constituting the cell do you mean the data source? Or the UICollectionViewDelegate? UICollectionViewDelegate does not do anything special for deletion right?

Comment: the deletion is not the problem. the problem is how your data source populates the cell...